# wpf How to remove rectangle(corner) line form border

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<DockPanel Margin="5,5,5,5" Background="Red"> //the line color refercence this.
    <DockPanel Margin="0,12,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Path Data="M 12,12 C 5,10.3 2.9,7.6 0.25,0.25 6.9,5.16 8.5,5.1 12,5" Fill="#EEEEEE" />
        <Border
            Margin="0,-6,0,0"
            Background="#EEEEEE"
            BorderBrush="#EEEEEE"
            BorderThickness="5"
            CornerRadius="5,5,5,5">
                <TextBlock>#Test</TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

I have create a Border to set the CornerRadius and BorderThickness, but the Border inside will show the rectangle(corner) line. May I know how to remove it?thanks.

[image: zoom]

Other case:

[image: other case]

Comment: What's the `WrapPanel` for?

Comment: I ran this code and I can not see any Rectangle inside it? Did you post correct code?

Comment: @GaurangDave  updated, please zoom in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve the issue.

```
<DockPanel Margin="5,5,5,5" Background="red">
    <DockPanel Margin="0,12,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Path Data="M 12,12 C 5,10.3 2.9,7.6 0.25,0.25 6.9,5.16 8.5,5.1 12,5" Fill="#EEEEEE" Margin="0,0,-1,0"/>
        <Border Margin="0,-6,0,0" Background="#EEEEEE" CornerRadius="5" Padding="5">
            <TextBlock>#Test</TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<DockPanel Margin="0,12,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Path Data="M 12,12 C 5,10.3 2.9,7.6 0.25,0.25 6.9,5.16 8.5,5.1 12,5" Fill="#EEEEEE" />
    <Border
        Margin="0,-6,0,0"
        Background="#EEEEEE"
        CornerRadius="5"
        Padding="5">
        <TextBlock>#Test</TextBlock>
    </Border>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Sorry, missed it entierly. Removing the border brush and thickness, and managing it via padding/margin works for me. I'll update my answer

Comment: I'm not seeing any light border on the left of the path? Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: There is a line (border) visible between `Path` and `Border`. Zoom in your design view in visual studio and you will see.

Comment: I'm definatley not seeing a border inbetween the path and the border. I'd be interested to see the artifact you are referring to.

Comment: @Gui Sorry I had to update your answer to show you image. You can delete it.